# Calculating distance to nearest object using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I would like to calculate the shortest distance between each building and nearest sewage pipe. I followed steps described on [CARTO blog](https://carto.com/blog/lateral-joins) but I encounerd an error.
I have data in same database but in different schemas:

- table name for buildings is **ks2_st** and schema is **public**
- table name for sewage pipes is **t2100_ill** and schema is **gji**

The query is:

```
SELECT 
  a.mid_st, 
  a.geometry, 
  ST_Distance(geography(b.geometry), geography(a.geometry)) as distance 
FROM  
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.geometry) 
  FROM public.ks2_st a) as buildings
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
(SELECT b._mid_gji, b.geometry 
  FROM gji.t2100_ill b
  ORDER BY a.geometry <-> b.geometry LIMIT 1) as sewery
```

When I try to run query I get message:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM" 
> LINE 7: FROM public.ks2_st a)
>   as buildings

Can you please help me find the error, because I do not know what the error could be?

Answer (score 5):

The error message is a bit misleading because the Syntax Error is in Line 5.
You're missing the `)` after the first `FROM` which leads to the error below in the code.

**Update:**

Also you have a **second Error**:
`DISTINCT ON (column)` is wrong. Either `DISTINCT column` or `DISTINCT ON (column) column` would be correct.

**Update 2:**

Another error: You named the subqueries *buildings* and *sewery*, you cannot use *a* and *b* outside of the subquery. Also these aliases are not needed, so I removed them. Additionally, I changed your `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` to a `,` because it is not needed here.

```
SELECT
buildings.mid_st,
buildings.geometry,
ST_Distance(buildings.geometry::geography, sewery.geometry::geography) as distance
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (geometry)
  geometry, mid_st
  FROM public.ks2_st
) as buildings,
(
  SELECT _mid_gji, geometry
  FROM gji.t2100_ill      
) as sewery
ORDER BY buildings.geometry <-> sewery.geometry
LIMIT 1
```

---

**Additional Hint when using PostgreSQL < 9.5:**

> [<-->:](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) For PostgreSQL below 9.5 only gives centroid distance of bounding boxes and for PostgreSQL 9.5+, does true KNN distance search giving true distance between geometries, and distance sphere for geographies.

You can use `LIMIT 10` in the subquery and then `ORDER BY ST_Distance(geom1,geom2) LIMIT 1` at the end as a workaround.

Comment: Still the same error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 8:   FROM public.ks2_st a

Comment: this is not the same error, it is a second one. I updated the answer.

Comment: I will try tomorrow again. I hope it will work. Thank you!

Comment: Still get the error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "a"
LINE 14:   ORDER BY a.geometry <-> b.geometry LIMIT 1

Comment: This is again a new Error... I did not proof-read your whole query. I'll update once more.

Comment: This is getting strange. Now it says that column does not exists (I checked and it exists): ERROR:  column buildings.mid_st does not exist
LINE 2: buildings.mid_st,

Comment: Of course you need to select it from your subquery :D You should learn more how to write SQL queries ;-) I updated again

Comment: I figure out that I need to include columns also in subquery.

Comment: Does it work now? then you could consider upvoting and accepting the answer ;-) Thanks.

Comment: Query runs and display result. For the first limit now I use value 10 and for the second limit I changed value to 20. In resulty the mid_st is displayed more than once which is not correct - it sholud be displayed only once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62581/discussion-between-rovo-and-miha-kl).